# Switching turns in JavaScript Tic-Tac-Toe?

Tags: javascript

I've got [this](http://pastie.org/7905370), any ideas of how I can get the program to switch turns between players with it?

Comment: What have you attempted to do to make this happen? What is your specific use case? There is not much I can do with a bunch of code like that - I'm not likely to take the time to get it all set up to answer the question you didn't appear to put much effort into. If you can provide more information and a simpler demonstration of the problem you're more likely to get a useful response.

Comment: See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I'm actually trying to help someone else :/

Comment: @user2109696 That doesn't change the fact that you went about asking this question in the wrong way.

Comment: I gave all of the information I have.  It was one function I didn't know how to solve at all, that apparently another user didn't have a problem taking a look at.  Please explain what I could have done further with the lack of first-hand knowledge I have, oh great 2006 reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this below your if(hasWon) clause:

```
var turnBtn = document.getElementById('turn');
turnBtn.value = (turnBtn.value == "X") ? "O" : "X";
```