# JS: detecting a win in a tictactoe game?

Tags: javascript

I am just doing some practice with a color alignment game.  I want to run a function after every move to see if it's winner but I can't figure out the best way to check if 3 colors are in a row or diagonal.  I guess I could iterate down the DOM tree each time and see if certain multiples are fulfilled but I don't know if that's the best option.

```js
(() => {
  let counter = 0;
  let conts = document.querySelectorAll('.parent div')
 
  conts.forEach(x => {
     x.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {  
        if (!!evt.target.style.backgroundColor) {
           return; 
        }
        counter++ 
        if (counter % 2 == 0) {
          evt.target.style.backgroundColor = "red"
        } else {
          evt.target.style.backgroundColor = "green"
        }
     })  
  });
})();
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  width: 40%;

}
.parent div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: check my answer to same question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65463817/how-can-i-check-winners-by-using-jquery/65464363#65464363

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this problem traversing the *grid* horizontally, vertically, and diagonally, in search of a sequence of "*boxes*" with the same color.

```
// used to walk the grid
const size = Math.sqrt(boxes.length);

// used to check grid columns, rows, and diagonal
const check = (color, index, inc = 1) => {
  for (let y = 0; y < size; y += inc) {
    let score = 0;
    for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
      // index callback to retrieve the next box
      if (boxes[index(x, y)].style.backgroundColor === color)
        score++;
      else
        break;
    }
    if (score === size)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

Whenever a color is set, you can perform such check via:

```
  if (
    // horizontally
    //    0 1 2,
    //    3 4 5,
    //    6 7 8
    check(color, (x, y) => (y * size) + x) ||

    // vertically
    //    0 3 6,
    //    1 4 7,
    //    2 5 8
    check(color, (x, y) => (y + (size * x))) ||

    // diagonally (y loops only once)
    //    0 4 8
    check(color, (x, y) => x * (size + 1), size) ||

    // diagonally (y loops only once)
    //    2 4 6
    check(color, (x, y) => ((x + 1) * (size - 1)), size)
  )
    alert(color + ' won!');
```

Differently from other answers, this logic is independent of the grid size.

You can [see the 3x3 live](https://codepen.io/WebReflection/pen/dypaBvB?editors=0011) and play around, but you can also see that without changing code [you can have a 4x4 grid too](https://codepen.io/WebReflection/pen/OJRdeOR?editors=0011).

The whole code in a nutshell:

```
(() => {
  let counter = 0;
  const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.parent div');
  const size = Math.sqrt(boxes.length);

  const check = (color, index, inc = 1) => {
    for (let y = 0; y < size; y += inc) {
      let score = 0;
      for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        if (boxes[index(x, y)].style.backgroundColor === color)
          score++;
        else
          break;
      }
      if (score === size)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  boxes.forEach(x => {
    x.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
      if (!!evt.target.style.backgroundColor)
        return;
      counter++;
      const color = counter % 2 ? "green" : "red";
      evt.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
      if (
        check(color, (x, y) => (y * size) + x) ||
        check(color, (x, y) => (y + (size * x))) ||
        check(color, (x, y) => x * (size + 1), size) ||
        check(color, (x, y) => ((x + 1) * (size - 1)), size)
      )
        alert(color + ' won!');
    })
  });
})();
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this.

```js
let counter = 0;
let winner = null;

const match = (player, row, col) => {
  const div = document.querySelector(`.parent #r${row}c${col}`);
  const bgColor = div.style.backgroundColor;
  return bgColor === player;
}

const win_hori = (player, row) => {
  return ![1, 2, 3].some(col => !match(player, row, col));
}

const win_verti = (player, col) => {
  return ![1, 2, 3].some(row => !match(player, row, col));
}

const win_slash = (player) => {
  return match(player, 1, 1) && match(player, 2, 2) && match(player, 3, 3);
}

const win_backslash = (player) => {
  return match(player, 3, 1) && match(player, 2, 2) && match(player, 1, 3);
}

const win = (player, row, col) => {
  return win_hori(player, row) || win_verti(player, col) || win_slash(player) || win_backslash(player);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.parent div').forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    const cell = evt.target;
    if (winner || !!cell.style.backgroundColor) {
      return;
    }
    const player = (++counter % 2 == 0) ? "red" : "green";
    cell.style.backgroundColor = player;
    const row = parseInt(cell.id.substring(1, 2));
    const col = parseInt(cell.id.substring(3, 4));
    if (win(player, row, col)) {
      winner = player;
      document.getElementById("winner").innerText = `${player} wins`;
    }
  })
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  width: 40%;

}
.parent div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="winner">nobody wins</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div id="r1c1"></div>
  <div id="r1c2"></div>
  <div id="r1c3"></div>
  <div id="r2c1"></div>
  <div id="r2c2"></div>
  <div id="r2c3"></div>
  <div id="r3c1"></div>
  <div id="r3c2"></div>
  <div id="r3c3"></div>
</div>
```